# Density of linear combination

Tags: asymptotics, combinations

Let $r_1, \ldots, r_n$ be a set of positive reals. Define 
\begin{equation*}
S = \{a_1r_1+\cdots+a_nr_n : a_i\in  \mathbb{N}\}. 
\end{equation*}
Define $\pi(x)= |\{a\in S:a<x\}|$. Is there an asymptotic formula for $\pi(x)$ as $x \to \infty$ ? For $n=1$, $\pi(x) \approx x/a_1 $. But I'm pretty unsure how to generalize this.

Comment: Personally I think the the tags (density) and (linear), which you have [created in this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1295484/revisions) should be removed altogether. The tags with ambiguous names which are used in various contexts are very probably going to be misused. But if you really see the need for creating these new tags, the very least you should do is describing the intended usage in the tag-excerpt and tag-wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can recast your problem in such a way that $\pi(x)$ is given by a (Quasi) [Ehrhart Polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrhart_polynomial).

Quoting from that wiki page:
In mathematics, an integral polytope has an associated Ehrhart polynomial that encodes the relationship between the volume of a polytope and the number of integer points the polytope contains. The theory of Ehrhart polynomials can be seen as a higher-dimensional generalization of Pick's theorem in the Euclidean plane.